# when passing data logs undefined

Tags: reactjs

The problem is really simple. I fetched the data and stored it in state. When passing to other components it logs okay, on a second render I get what I want(array of objects). But when I pass the same array to Fahrzeugdaten component, I get undefined on a second render.
PS. No need to write about different ways of state management, I need a simple answer.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  Datenschutz,
  Fahrzeugangebote,
  Fahrzeugankauf,
  Finanzierung,
  Galerie,
  Home,
  Impressum,
  Kontakt,
  Fehler404,
  Fahrzeugdaten,
} from './pages';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';


const App = () => {
  const [carsList, setCarsList] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCars();
  }, []);

  const fetchCars = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url);
      const data = res.data;
      setCarsList(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data.error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/datenschutz' element={<Datenschutz />} />
        <Route
          path='/fahrzeugangebote'
          element={<Fahrzeugangebote />}
        />
        <Route path='/fahrzeugankauf' element={<Fahrzeugankauf />} />
        <Route path='/finanzierung' element={<Finanzierung />} />
        <Route path='/galerie' element={<Galerie />} />
        <Route path='/impressum' element={<Impressum />} />
        <Route path='/kontakt' element={<Kontakt />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<Fehler404 />} />
        <Route path='/fahrzeugdaten/:id'
          element={<Fahrzeugdaten carsList={carsList} />}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Fahrzeugdaten component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Header, Navbar, Jumbotrone, Logo, CarPage } from '../components';

const Fahrzeugdaten = ({ carsList }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div id='header-img-id' className='header-img-div'>
        <Header />
        <Navbar />
        <div className='mka__logo-img'>
          <div className='mka__logo-size'>
            <Logo />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='mka__title-wrapper'>
          <div className='mka__container'>
            <h1 className='mka__title'>FAHRZEUGDATEN</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <CarPage />
      </div>
      <Jumbotrone />
    </>
  );
};

export default Fahrzeugdaten;
```

Comment: it is unclear what your error is. Also order of <Route> is important, your Fahrzeugdaten route cannot be reached based on your sample.

Comment: Changed the order and still getting undefined when console.log(carsList) in Fahrzeugdaten component. I put <Route> with Fahrzeugdaten component first.

Comment: its undefined on 1st render not second, so set it empty array `useState([])`.

Comment: I assume your console.log is in the Fahrzeugdaten component ? can you share the code of this component too ? Also did you debug and make sure the setCarsList is called ?

Comment: @bogdanoff it renders undefined on both 1st and 2nd render, only in Fahrzeugdaten component. In other component I get expected result, on second render I get what I want

Comment: @JiaSH Added the code in post. There I console.log(carsList). Yes its called. In all other components I get it right, just this one I cant figure it out why its not behaving as expected.

Comment: carsList isnt used in the Fahrzeugdaten component that you shared :p sorry but it is hard to find the problem if we dont see it :D

Comment: @JiaSH I pass it to <CarPage> component. Im prop drilling but thats not the point. I should have my passed state on second render in the component and all I get is undefined.

Comment: the error probably lies somewhere in the code we dont see - because what you shared here seems ok :) have you tried to build a reproducable example ?

Comment: @JiaSH I deleted and rewrote CarPage component and it worked! I dont know how, because for two hours I was trying everything.. Well thank for ideas on where could error be. Many thank to you and hopefully I will get a chance one day to go to France :)

Comment: Good to know it worked ;) wish you the best !